# Algorithm to find best alignment of one curve onto another

Tags: image-processing, pattern-recognition

So I've boiled a certain problem I have down to the point where I have two images of (approximately) the same scale.  One which contains a closed curve, and one which is a partial curve.  I want to determine what rotation and translation (and possibly scale, though for now that is not required) will best map the partial curve onto the closed curve.

Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD8k3.png) shows an illustration of my desired behavior.  (The partial outline has been slightly inflated just so that it is easier to see the final overlap)

The angle and translation can be pretty much anything, and the sometimes the partial curve will not match the outline curve at all.  This alignment would need to tell me both how to transform the partial curve such that it best overlaps the outline, or alternatively, that it isn't a very good match.

While I'm reasonably proficient with regression and other estimation techniques, the fact that these points are unlabeled and so there are no correspondences from one to the other leaves me a bit stumped as to how to even approach this.

Is there a simple/standard way to approach this sort of problem?

[image: Desired Behavior]

Comment: How do you measure which mapping is "best"?  "Best" is vague.  Do you have a measure of similarity in mind?

Comment: You might find it helpful to become familiar with  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-set_registration

Comment: Hi Christian. This problem is not particularly easy in general. An option is ICP iterations, but you need a sufficiently good starting position.

For this particular case, you could pick three distant points on the curve to align and compare to points triples properly sampled along the reference.